# Trouble with NGINX Config to install WHMCS

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config, whmcs

I have no idea what I should write in my Nginx config file to start my WHMCS install. I have put the WHMCS folder from the download in var/www/html, and renamed it to billing. My config file is below. Currently, when I run IP/billing/install (as mentioned in the whims installation guide), I get a file downloaded to my browser. Please help.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    #location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    
    #}

            # WHMCS CONFIG
        # When WHMCS updates, make sure to get the newest configuration at https://hostup.org/blog/whmcs-friendly-urls-configuration-for-nginx/

        location ~ /billing/announcements/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/announcements/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/download/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/download$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/knowledgebase/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/store/ssl-certificates/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/ssl-certificates/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/store/sitelock/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/sitelock/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/store/website-builder/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/website-builder/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/store/order/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/order/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/cart/domain/renew/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/cart/domain/renew$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/account/paymentmethods/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/account/paymentmethods$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/password/reset/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/password/reset/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/account/security/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/account/security$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/subscription?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/subscription$1;
        }

    #Social media authorization
        location ~ /billing/auth/provider/google_signin/finalize/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=auth/provider/google_signin/finalize$1;
        }

     #WHMCS ADMIN
    location ~ /billing/admin/(addons|apps|search|domains|help\/license|services|setup|utilities\/system\/php-compat)(.*) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/$1$2 last; 
        }

        location ~ /billing/admin/client/?(.*)/paymethods/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/client/?(.*)/paymethods/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/admin/setup/auth/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/setup/auth/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/admin/client/?(.*)/tickets/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/client/?(.*)/tickets/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/admin/client/?(.*)/invoice/?(.*)/capture/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/client/?(.*)/invoice/?(.*)/capture/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/admin/account/security/two-factor/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/account/security/two-factor/$1;
        }

        location ~ /billing/admin/search/intellisearch?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/search/intellisearch/$1;
        }

    # Security Advisory 2020-01-28
        location ^~ /vendor/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
        }
    # END WHMCS CONFIG
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this proplem happend in Nginx

fix is simple

delete htaccess file
and
go to general setting
and scroll dowen to Friendly URLs

make Friendly URLs  is basic urls

just it

it will convert all url to end with .php

and all whmcs url will work fine

[wppit](https://www.wppit.com/)